# jruby on rails with oracle throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails

I am a newbie in jruby on rails. I have created a basic application using rails and generated the war file and deployed in tomcat container. when i start the application i get the below error. I am using using oracle and have uncommented the following entry under the config/warble.rb file:

```
config.gems += ["activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]

Nov 22, 2012 8:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: ERROR: application error
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter could not load Oracle JDBC driver. Please install ojdbc6.jar library.
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_jdbc_connection.rb:35:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1019:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1019:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:116:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1019:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1699:in `instance_eval'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:36:in `(root)'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter.rb:12:in `OracleEnhancedRailtie'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /tomcat/tomcat/webapps/phonebook2/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_l
```

Thanks and regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Add the ojdbc6.jar as dependencies under the lib directory of WEB-INF under the webapps directory in tomcat.